# Get only child elements from xml, without data modification using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Could you help me,please? I have a document

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Transport version="1.0">
           <Car>
              <Model version="1.0">
                <!-- some comment -->
                 <ENGINE>
                    <water>blue</water>
                    <S00589>
                       <E005766>Test</E005766>
                    </S00589>
                 </ENGINE>
                 <OIL>
                    <E007412>test</E007412>
                    <E1450062>test</E1450062>
                 </OIL>
                <!-- some comment -->
              </Model>
           </Car>
        </Transport>
```

And I need get children for Model with text, attributes and tags.
I try to use that xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:copy-of select="//Model/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I get empty lines before and after output.
When I use that xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:copy-of select="//Model/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the correct information, but I lose the spaces; I need to get the original text. It is very important for me. I expect this output

```
<ENGINE>
    <water>blue</water>
    <S00589>
       <E005766>Test</E005766>
    </S00589>
 </ENGINE>
 <OIL>
    <E007412>test</E007412>
    <E1450062>test</E1450062>
 </OIL>
```

I want to get text which start with `<ENGINE>` and finish with `</OIL>`. I haven't to get the spaces between `<Model version="1.0">` and `<ENGINE>`, but I need to
get the text with spaces between  `<ENGINE>` and `<water>blue</water>`. I want to get original text.
Thank you very much. Sorry if I described the problem poorly, this is my first time here.
I want to get only what is highlighted
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4rVJ.jpg)

Comment: I want to get text which start with <ENGINE> and finish with </OIL>. I haven't to get spaces between  <Model version="1.0"> and <ENGINE>  , but I need to 
     get text with spaces between  <ENGINE> and <water>blue</water>. I want to get original text.
     Thank you very much. Sorry if I described the problem poorly,this is my first time here.

Comment: The spaces you are speaking about are not a part of any text nodes. I suppose you want to preserve is the indentation of the XML file, isn't it?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Thank you for your help. I attached image with text that I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to get an output similar to what you show is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//Model/*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does **not** copy the white-space text nodes from the original XML; it creates new indentation of the output.

If you do want to copy the original indentation, but remove the opening and closing white-space text nodes (not sure why you would need to do such thing), you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Model/node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Model/text()[1] | Model/text()[last()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the result in both cases is an XML fragment. A well-formed XML document must have a single root element.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I don't want to have well-formed XML document, I want to get original text which contain  text from <ENGINE> to </OIL>, unfortunately your xslt saves spaces between <Model version="1.0"> and <ENGINE>, but I want save spaces only between <ENGINE> and </OIL>. Could you help me,please? For example: if I have  comments between <Model version="1.0"> and <ENGINE> your xslt saves it, but I don't want it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I attached image with text that I want to get.

Comment: I believe my 2nd suggestion returns the result you show. I still don't see why this is important. FYI, there is no such thing as "text from <ENGINE> to </OIL>". XSLT works on the XML tree, which may contain text nodes. -- If you have comments (which your example does not show), you can remove them using an empty template.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgotten to add comments in example. I edited it.How can I remove this comments and spaces in my result? Thank you

Comment: You can remove comments using `<xsl:template match="commentt()"/>`. -- You still did not explain what is the purpose of this exercise. I think I gave you at least a starting point, but I find the problem uninteresting and will not spend any more time on it.